# Is boost::posix_time::ptime safe to store in a Windows shared memory map?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I want to store a `boost::posix_time::ptime` object in a Windows shared memory map for multiple processes.

However, for this to be safe, `ptime` cannot have pointers to other places in memory (i.e. it needs to be a POD) or else the various processes accessing the memory map will run into problems because parts of the `ptime` object are owned by another process.

So is `ptime` safe to store in a Windows shared memory map?

Comment: Whatever the current implementation, nothing is guaranteed in the documentation so nothing is guaranteed to be the same in upcoming versions of Boost...

Comment: Consider copying what you need out of ptime into a your own POD structure and then shove that in shared memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up converting boost's `ptime` into microseconds based off the Unix epoch, like this:

```
#define MICROSECONDS_PER_SECOND 1000000
boost::posix_time::ptime unixEpoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970, boost::gregorian::Jan, 1));

boost::posix_time::time_duration deltaTime = timestamp - unixEpoch; 
boost::int64_t microsecondsAfterEpoch =
    deltaTime.ticks() / (deltaTime.ticks_per_second() / MICROSECONDS_PER_SECOND);
```

I could have easily just used `deltaTime.ticks()`, but then I would also have needed to keep track of `deltaTime.ticks_per_second()`. For my case, microseconds was enough precision.